# Suppose $|G| = \infty$. Then there is an elment $g$ of $G$ with an $o(g) = \infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ a group. Suppose $|G| = \infty$. Then there is an elment $g$ of $G$ with an $o(g) = \infty$.

That's true? Intuitively it seems so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Nope. There are infinite groups where every element except the identity has order $2.$

Comment: See [Example of infinite groups such that all its elements are of finite order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155521/example-of-infinite-groups-such-that-all-its-elements-are-of-finite-order)

Comment: Of course it's very easy to construct counterexamples to your conjecture, but what is interesting is that there are finitely generated infinite groups with every element of finite order. The best known example is the Grigorchuk group.

Comment: You might find it interesting to read about the history of the Burnside Problem.

Answer (score 5):

In general this is not true.

For example, consider

1) $\Bbb{Q} / \Bbb{Z}$

2) $\{z \in \Bbb{C} : z^n=1\; \text{for some n $\in$ $\Bbb{N}$}\}$

Answer (score 4):

It is false.

Consider the set $\Bbb G_n$ of sequences of elements from $\Bbb Z_n$, the finite cyclic group with $n$ elements where $2 \le n \in \Bbb N$.  We may think of an element $g \in \Bbb G_n$ as an $\infty$-tuple

$g = (z_1, z_2, z_3, \ldots); \tag 1$

if

$h = (y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots), \tag 2$

we may define an operation component-wise:

$gh = (z_1 + h_1, z_2 + h_2, z_3 + h_3, \ldots); \tag 3$

it is easy to see $\Bbb G_n$ is a group under this operation, and that for $g \in \Bbb G_n$,

$g^n = (nz_1, nz_2, nz_3, \ldots) = (0, 0, 0, \ldots), \tag 4$

where $(0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ is the identity element of $\Bbb G_n$.  Thus every element of $\Bbb G_n$ is of finite order at most $n$, though clearly

$\vert \Bbb G_n \vert = \infty. \tag 5$